# Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Image.get'

Tags: c#, winforms

i have tried the following code in c# winform

```
 private void ComboCar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
        opf.Filter = "Choose Image(*.jpg; *.png; *.gif)|*.jpg; *.png; *.gif";
        if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
        }
    }
```

but I'm getting the error

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Image.get'

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are methods that you can call without making an object of the class. You can just call it from where you want. 
example: `String.IsNullOrWhitespace("exampleString")` is a static method.

Non-Static methods are methods where you have to make an instance of your object. This is what your PictureBox.Image.Get is, check this example for fix
Example:

```
PictureBox box = new PictureBox();
box.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

`PictureBox` is the name of the class of the control on your form. You need to use the name of the actual PictureBox on your form, for example

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
```